# Android Couldn't get connection factory client

Tags: android, client, maps, factory

OK, so I have a working app that I'm testing in 2 android emulators one based on API 8 and the other on API 11. The app works fine in API 11 but fails in API 8 with the Couldn't get connection factory client error message.

I'm wondering if this might be to do with several things

- Maybe I need to get a different Google Maps API key for different builds?
- Maybe I need different declarations in my Manifest file for it to work for different builds?
- Maybe something else?

In the project properties I have selected the Project Build Target as Google Maps API 8 and have downloaded all the appropriate SDKs I need.

Any help from you would be much appreciated, thanks for your interest, meanwhile here's my Manifest file...

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="net.rogw.p352lbs"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />

        <activity
            android:name="net.rogw.p352lbs.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Here's my layout file, I'm not adding the java file as it is lengthy and works fine with an API 11 emulator:-

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <com.google.android.maps.MapView
        android:id="@+id/mapView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:apiKey="Key is not shown here but it is a valid string"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:enabled="true" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: which apiversion are you using api v1 or api v2?. looks like you are using api v1 which is deprecated.

Comment: API V2 I think but not sure I know how to check.

Comment: i don't see the meta tag inside application tag. Do you reference google play services library project?. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/

Comment: also post your activity code and the xml layout code

Answer (score 0):

Use this support map fragment instead of map fragment in your xml:

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/map"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>
```

Comment: how did you know when op has not mentioned the same?

Comment: In a general think, most of the developers go wrong with this only. That's why I have suggested him like that

Answer (score 0):

You are using map api v1 which is deprecated. You should use map api v2.

Change your xml

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/map"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>
```

You will use `SupportMapFragment` if you want to support api level 11 and below.

You will also need to reference google play services library project in your android map project.

http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html

Your Activity class should extend `FragmentActivity`

Then

You need to have the api key in the meta tag inside application tag.

You will need few more permissions in the manifest file

More info @

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#overview

Remove

```
<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
```

Comment: Thanks #Raghunandan, looks like I've work to do. I'll go off now and report back in due course. Appreciate your input, thanks again.